# MSBuild ItemGroup with condition

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuildextensionpack

I don't know if `ItemGroup` is the right type to use. I will get 4 different booleans that will be true or false depending on choice.

I would like to fill up an `ItemGroup` with this "strings" depending on the true or false. Is that possible or what should I use?

Example

```
Anders = true
Peter = false
Michael = false
Gustaf = true
```

My `ItemGroup` should then have
Anders and Gustaf.

Is that possible or how should I solve that?

Comment: what are these "strings"? Are they in a text file? Are they msbuild properties? Also, please check your spelling. It's `ItemGroup` not `iteamgroup`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you have a bunch of items, it would be better to store them in an `ItemGroup` from the start since after all that is what it is meant for and it also allows transformations etc. For example this achieves what you want:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Names Include="Anders">
    <Value>True</Value>
  </Names>
  <Names Include="Peter">
    <Value>False</Value>
  </Names>
  <Names Include="Michael">
    <Value>False</Value>
  </Names>
  <Names Include="Gustaf">
    <Value>True</Value>
  </Names>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="GetNames">

  <ItemGroup>
    <AllNames Include="%(Names.Identity)" Condition="%(Names.Value)==true"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="@(AllNames)"/>  <!--AllNames contains Anders and Gustaf-->
</Target>
```

However if they must be properties, I do not think there is another way than enumerating them all manually like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <Anders>True</Anders>
  <Peter>False</Peter>
  <Michael>False</Michael>
  <Gustaf>True</Gustaf>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="GetNames">

  <ItemGroup>
    <AllNames Include="Anders" Condition="$(Anders)==true"/>
    <AllNames Include="Peter" Condition="$(Peter)==true"/>
    <AllNames Include="Michael" Condition="$(Michael)==true"/>
    <AllNames Include="Gustaf" Condition="$(Gustaf)==true"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="@(AllNames)"/>
</Target>
```